# Variable number of parameters in routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I know we can set parameters in router paths using `'/:id'`. But I want to create an array of uncertain length like this: `'/:id1/:id2/:id3/...'`

Currently I'm managing up to three parameters like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '/:name1',  component: MyComponent,   canActivate: [ LocalUserGuard ] },
    { path: '/:name1/:name2',  component: MyComponent,   canActivate: [ LocalUserGuard ] },
    { path: '/:name1/:name2/:name3',  component: MyComponent,   canActivate: [ LocalUserGuard ] }
```

However I want to extend it to any number of parameters.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Where are all of those different IDs supposed to end up?

Comment: Each ID refers to an array of objects, and each objects can further contain an array of objects(which refers to the nested IDs) and so on.... So I wan't to navigate to these different IDs and display its data using MyComponent

Answer (score 7):

If you want it to be completely arbitrary, you could use a [wildcard route](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#wildcard):

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**', component: MyComponent, canActivate: [ LocalUserGuard ] },
]
```

Then inside `MyComponent` you can access the URL segments via the `ActivatedRoute`:

```ts
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent { 
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.url.subscribe((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
      // do whatever you need to with the segments
    });
  }
}
```

See example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9YYMwO?p=preview

Comment: Actually I'm having these components under another route 'view/'. So I tried 'view/**' but it's not working. It's giving error: Cannot match any routes. URL segment: 'view/myname'

Comment: @Rohan please do include the relevant context in your questions. Have you tried making the wildcard match part of the `children` of the `'view'` route?

Comment: No I haven't put it under children. Since if I put it as a child of 'view' I will have to put a router component to my ViewComponent , but I don't want that. I want it in my AppComponent itself.

Comment: @Rohan *"I will have to put a router component to my ViewComponent"* - what? Please edit the question to clarify what you're actually doing.

Comment: @Rohan I've updated the Plunker example and it seems to work fine, not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Oh... I meant router-outlet... I'm very sorry for that mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147555/discussion-between-rohan-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 6):

You can use  [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) to match to any type of Url you want.

```
function tagRoute(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  if(url[0].path.match('tags-list'))
  {
    return ({consumed: url})
  }else {
    return null;
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{matcher: tagRoute, component: TagComponent },  
{path:'**', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

And then you can use **ActivatedRoute** inside **TagComponent** to fetch url segments as @johnrsharpe mentioned above.

```
this.activateRoute.url.subscribe((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
    segments.shift();
    segments.join('/');
});
```